# Generating relative url in Middleman in tag's attribute

Tags: relative-path, middleman, static-pages

I need to get a relative url in the `data-original` attribute of `img` tag like this:

```
<img data-original="../imf/72932.png" src="../i/72932.jpg" />
```

But I'm getting

```
<img data-original="/imf/10163.jpg" src="../i/10163.jpg" />
```

As you can see, by setting `set :relative_links, true` in `config.rb` I can get a relative link in `img`'s `src` but not in the `data-original` attribute with:

```
<%= image_tag  img_url,   {  "data-original" => original_path }  %>
```

where `original-path` is defined like this

```
<% original-path = "/imf/#{ wiz.file }"   %>
```

It works of course when the site is generated dynamically in development but not when it is built statically. Is there any way to make `original_path` work like a relative path?

Comment: There is a workaround described in [Deployment on a sub-Uri](http://ict4g.net/adolfo/notes/2014/10/30/switching-to-middleman.html#deployment-on-a-sub-uri) but that's not exactly what I'm after as it requires per site configuration so this setup in not 100% relative.

Comment: P.S. The `:http_prefix` seems to conflict with something. It works when you rename it to something else